# IE-7: expected identifier, string or number: no trailing comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, ie7.js

I am getting the **expected identifier, string or number** error in IE-7.

There is no trailing comma in the code

```
// Merge defaults with options 
options = (options) ? options : {};
options = copyProperties({logging:true},options);
var appId = options.appId || options.apiKey;
if (/number|string/.test(typeof appId)) {
Runtime.setClientID(appId.toString());
}
```

The error occour after the 2nd line

```
options = copyProperties({logging:true},options);
```

Comment: should it be `options = copyProperties({"logging":true},options);`? With quotes around `"logging"` ?

Comment: is there any difference between single and double quotes?

Comment: Yes, to be a valid JSON object, it must use double quotes I believe

Comment: @DelightedD0D I have quoted the object key with double quotes, now the page is loading infinitely without showing the content and with no error